# HTML issue: Is it okay if I close a parent element and then a child node?

Tags: html, dom, tags

I would like to know if **HTML5** allows you to **mix tags** like this:

```
<u>hello <i>wor</u>ld</i>
```

Although it seems to work as expected in the latest versions of the most popular browsers, I would like to know if it is ok to use it on my webpage.

I'm aware of its **incompatibility with the DOM**. Because of this, the browser parses it this way:

```
<u>hello </u><i><u>worl</u>ld</i>
```

So these are my questions:

> - What does the **HTML5 specification** say about this? **And** the **HTML4.01** spec?
> - Is this a **good** practice? (**or** not so **bad** at least)
> - Are there any **differences** among **browsers**? (Is this cross-browser-compatible?)

Comment: It's not OK to use in any version of HTML. Modern browsers will just try to work around it.

Comment: @Pekka 웃 . I think so but what does the spec say about it?

Comment: The spec expects well-formedness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I FOUND THEM!** They are called **misnested inline tags**. Here is the link to the HTML5 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#misnested-tags:-b-i-/b-/i

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not okay.

HTML - of any version - expects [well-formedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element), which Wikipedia defines thus (emphasis mine):

> In web page design, and generally for all markup languages such as
>   SGML, HTML, and XML, a well-formed element is one that is either
>
> - opened and subsequently closed,
> - an empty element, which in that case must be terminated,
> - **properly nested so that it does not overlap.**

your browser may accept it and try to work around it, but it is not okay according to the standard.

Comment: +1 However wikipedia isn't always a reliable reference. I expected a link to the HTML5 spec or something. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I can find the reference only for XML: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-wellformed It's bound to be there somewhere for SGML / HTML as well if you search long enough.

Answer (score 1):

When validating your html against the HTML5 specifications using the W3 validator it gives the following error.

[image: HTML5 validation error]

When validated against the HTML 4.01 specifications, the following errors are given.

[image: HTML 4.01 validation error]

Comment: +1 Good point on the validator. However that doesn't really answer my question: where are that nesting rules you talk about defined? Thanks anyway :)